# How do I create templates for displaying posts in a category page using Twenty Thirteen child theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to setup my category archives in Twenty Thirteen. So far they fetch all the right posts and contain all the neccessary elements. Now I wish to style these elements and also edit the layout. The problem is I don't know where to do this. It is worth noting that this is my very first site and that I am a beginner.

Below is the code from my category.php. I understand that it uses functions to get the data but I don't get where the html/css for these elements is set.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <header class="archive-header">
            <h1 class="archive-title"><?php
                if ( is_day() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Dagsarkiv: %s', 'twentythirteen' ), get_the_date() );
                elseif ( is_month() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Månadsarkiv: %s', 'twentythirteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentythirteen' ) ) );
                elseif ( is_year() ) :
                    printf( __( 'Kategoriarkiv: %s', 'twentythirteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentythirteen' ) ) );
                else :
                    _e( 'Archives', 'twentythirteen' );
                endif;
            ?></h1>
        </header><!-- .archive-header -->

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: Those functions aren't outputting any html content. I think you may want to look for the "content" template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twentythirteen makes use of [post-formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). This is quite an extensive section that you can go and read on in the link provided. With this formats, the loop elements has been removed inside the loop and is moved to a couple of files, one for each format.

This is the twenty thirteen loop

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

For the "standard" format (which is not a post format, but actually a noun for all posts without a designated post-format), the loop will be in `content.php`. A post format like `video` will be content-video.php. All these different templates are called in the loop with this line

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

OK, now, with all these in mind, I think what the best here will be is the following

- Copy `content.php` to you child theme. While you at it, also copy `category.php` to your child theme. We will change these two files
- Now, rename `content.php` to something like `content-category.php`
- Open up `content-category.php` and edit it as you like. Remove what is not needed and add what is needed. Save this file
- Lastly, open up category.php and change the get_template part to call this new content file. So this line `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` needs to change to `get_template_part( 'content', 'category' );`
- You can now just change the css accordingly

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)